# There is no "non color" in color space

Tags: node-editor

There is no "non color" in color space

[image]

Comment: Click where it reads sRGB. What are the options that show?

Comment: Only linear and sRGB

Comment: what format is the image? How did you install blender? Are you using the default OCIO configuration or a custom one?

Comment: Linear is effectively non-color since it doesn’t apply the sRGB conversions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I changed his download location. It's ready to use now.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Linear' option is effectively the same as the non-color option elsewhere, since it doesn’t apply the sRGB conversions.